# Insert a MySQL row only if the data in the specific columns does not already exists in the table somewhere

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

The following table has been created:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    url VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, email, phone, url)
);
```

The goal is to enter a new row only if the email or phone of that row do not already exist somewhere in the table.

In other words, how to avoid entering duplicate email or url values to the whole table: if the email or phone already exists in the table somewhere, do not enter the entire new row.

Which script to use? It would be even better if it was a Python entry.

Comment: What have you tried, and why didn't it work? We're happy to help you fix your code, not so much to write it for you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about it. Next time I'm more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define both rows as [UNIQUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) and so mysql doesn't let you enter the same email or number twice.

But you shouldn't make the number unique, then two people can share the same number.

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
    id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    url VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, email, phone, url)
);
```